# Product and sum without addtional memory allocation

Tags: python, numpy, broadcasting

Is there away to multiply two arrays and sum along an axis (or multiple axes) without allocating extra memory?

In this example:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.random.random((10, 10, 10))
B = np.random.random((10, 10, 10))

C = np.sum(A[:, None, :, :, None] * B[None, :, None, :, :], axis=(-1,-2))
```

When computing C, an intermediate matrix of size 10x10x10x10x10 is created only to be collapsed immediately. Is there a way to avoid this in numpy?

Comment: Do you want `C = A @ B.T`?

Comment: @mozway, not always, but I am realizing the example is too simple. I updated to be more requiring of broadcasting.

Comment: As the comments show a sum-of-products can often be cast as a `dot` of some sort.  But more generally if you want to avoid this kind of large intermediate result, and still want compiled speed, you may have to use `numba`..

Comment: @hpaulj couldn't this be achieved with `einsum`? `np.einsum('ikl,jlm->ijk', A, B)`

Comment: @mozway,  I meant `of some sort` to include `einsum`.  That's the most general sum-of-products tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a dot product with the transpose of the second array:

```
C = A @ B.T
```

*NB. The operation in the original question was: `C = np.sum(A[:, None, :] * B[None, :, :], axis=-1)`.*

Quick check:

```
C1 = np.sum(A[:, None, :] * B[None, :, :], axis=-1)
C2 = A @ B.T

assert np.allclose(C1, C2)
```

You can generalize with [`einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html):

```
np.einsum('ikl,jlm->ijk', A, B)
```

Quick check:

```
A = np.random.random((2, 3, 4))
B = np.random.random((2, 4, 5))

#             i    j   k  l    m         i   j    k   l  m
C1 = np.sum(A[:, None, :, :, None] * B[None, :, None, :, :], axis=(-1,-2))
C2 = np.einsum('ikl,jlm->ijk', A, B)

assert np.allclose(C1, C2)
```